# Proof the inequalitiy for the two Matrices $A, B$

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Let $ A,B \in C^{nxn}$ then

$$ 1 \le || (\lambda I-B)^{-1})(A-B)||\le ||(\lambda I-B)^{-1}||*||(A-B)||$$

for any eigenvalue $\lambda $ of $ A $ which is not an eigenvalue of $ B$ and any operator norm.

The second inequalitiy is easily obtained using the multiplicative property of the operator norm.
However, how do I proof  $1 \le || (\lambda I-B)^{-1})(A-B)||$ ?

Can someone give me a hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e. $Av=\lambda v$. Then $(\lambda I-B)^{-1}(A-B)v=(\lambda I-B)^{-1}(\lambda I -B)v=v $. Hence by definition of the operator norm, $\left\|(\lambda I-B)^{-1}(A-B)\right\|\geq 1$. Question: Where did we use that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue for $B$?

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a unit eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\lambda$, we have
$$
(\lambda I-B)^{-1}(A-B)x=(\lambda I-B)^{-1}(\lambda I-B)x=x
$$
and hence
$$
1=\|x\|=\|(\lambda I-B)^{-1}(A-B)x\|\leq\|(\lambda I-B)^{-1}(A-B)\|.
$$